# IP hiding attempts are detected

Tags: vpn, proxy, tor

So I am using Tor and I try to log into a certain web site. It gives me a message saying that my IP address was used for spamming and does not let me log in. I think ok, probably the exit node is compromised. So I create a new circuit for the web site, no luck, exit node IP changes, but receiving the same error.

Tried some free VPNs and Proxies, getting the same message. However when I try to log in without any anonymity tools, login works just fine.

It seems like they keep the database of all Tor exit nodes, free (and maybe paid) vpn servers and proxies and deny login if users arrive from them.

This seriously hinders anonymous web surfing. Is there any workaround, preferably a free one? How to deal with web services which filter out third party IPs?

Comment: Have you considered using other web sites? It doesn't sound like that one respects your privacy (probably due to abuse from proxies/Tor/etc.).

Comment: Well, that site has the information I need

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/182711/235964

Comment: Related: [Why do site operators block legal VPNs?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/251970/why-do-site-operators-block-legal-vpns). In short: they might not block you to hinder anonymous surfing but because anonymous access is significantly more connected to abuse than non-anonymous access. This also means that there is usually no easy way around this block since if there would one it would be abused too.

Comment: Thanks for related links guys, it is interesting info though I am mainly interested not on why, but rather on how to bypass it. Seems like there is no easy way.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple VPN detection services available. Most of them use a combination of detection techniques, but the main one they all seem to use is to check the organisation that owns the IP address.

Most VPNs will use an IP address that is owned by a datacentre, which will be easily detected by their system. If you use a VPN service that uses an IP address registered to a residential ISP, there is much less chance of detection - but these are often much more expensive.

Comment: [citation needed]. My personal experience contradicts with your statement. I regularly browse without any issue with a VPN with an endpoint in a huge and well known datacenter. While I was kicked a few times, I browse mostly without issues. While browsing Tor or a commercial VPN (one with lots of ads on Youtube), I often encounter issues while browsing. So, the filtering does not appear to be based on the organization owning the IP of the endpoint.